# ASP.NET MVC Acces denied to write in folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am currently trying to download a generated PDF.
The C# Code is allright, I guess but the problem is that it gives me a error:

```
Access to the path 'C:\temp' is denied.
```

I tried to grant permission to this folder by

```
right click -> properties -> security -> edit -> add
```

I could not find any user named ASPNET? So I tried to add NETWORKSERVICE IIS_IUSRS and even All and Everyone did not work..

What am I doing wrong here?

Code:

```
public ActionResult GeneratePDF(WorkReportModel model)
{
    return File("C:\\temp", "application/pdf", "MyRenamedFile.pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C:\Temp is a **Directory**, so you cannot send it as a file.....
I am sure you meant something like;

```
public ActionResult GeneratePDF(WorkReportModel model)
{
    return File("C:\\temp\\theActualFileName.pdf", "application/pdf", "MyRenamedFile.pdf");
}
```

See MSDN documentation on file method:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File%28System.String,System.String,System.String%29

```
protected internal virtual FilePathResult File(
    string fileName,
    string contentType,
    string fileDownloadName
)
Parameters:

fileName Type: System.String
The path of the file to send to the response.
```

You are sending C:\temp to the FILE name parameter...